# Does groupby in pandas create a copy of the data or just a view?

Tags: python, pandas

Does `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` create a copy of the data or just a view? In the (more probable) case of not creating a copy, what is the additional memory overhead and how does it scale with the original dataframe chracteristics (e.g. number of rows, columns, distinct groups)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [groupby code in pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py) gets a bit complex so it's hard to find out from first principles. A quick test makes it seem like the memory use grows as the data grows and that more groups = more memory, but it doesn't appear to making a full copy or anything:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000,5)))

In [8]: def ret_df(df):
   ...:     return df

In [9]: def ret_gb_df(df):
   ...:     return df, df.groupby(0).mean()

In [10]: %memit ret_df(df)
peak memory: 75.91 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB

In [11]: %memit ret_gb_df(df)
peak memory: 75.96 MiB, increment: 0.05 MiB

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100000,5)))

In [13]: %memit ret_df(df)
peak memory: 79.76 MiB, increment: -0.02 MiB

In [14]: %memit ret_gb_df(df)
peak memory: 94.88 MiB, increment: 15.12 MiB

In [15]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((1000000,5)))

In [16]: %memit ret_df(df)
peak memory: 113.98 MiB, increment: 0.01 MiB

In [17]: %memit ret_gb_df(df)
peak memory: 263.14 MiB, increment: 149.16 MiB

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1,2,3], (1000000, 5)))

In [19]: %memit ret_df(df)
peak memory: 95.34 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB

In [20]: %memit ret_gb_df(df)
peak memory: 166.91 MiB, increment: 71.56 MiB
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed analysis! Indeed the source code was a bit complex and the `%memit` magic command proved to be an effective tool.
Some remarks:
- It appears that there is minimal memory overhead in the case of a relatively small dataframe of shape `(1000, 5)`. However, this overhead scales in absolute terms in a roughly linear manner with respect to the dataframe size, while the memory of the dataframe itself, counter-intuitively scales extremely sub-linearly with the dataframe size: a x1000 dataframe takes only x1.5 memory! I wonder why...

Comment: As a result, the relative memory overhead reaches more than 100% for the biggest dataframe, which is equivalent to copying.

Comment: As your final experiment demonstrated, the number of groups doesn't really seem to have an influence; the memory overhead is about 100% even in the case of a vastly smaller number of groups.

Comment: @Ataxias I think `groupby` stores indexes for each group, e.g. `sorted_index[start[i]:end[i]]` are positions of elements from ith group. Then when you use `groupby` for computation, you iterate over groups: at each iteration, data corresponding to current group is copied and exists until garbage collected at the end of iteration. That is, the data copy overhead is ~25% for 4 groups, ~50% for 2 groups and ~1% for 100 groups of equal size. This is consistent with your last comment. My guess is based on briefly tracing through the code without going too much into details.

Answer (score 6):

I did a little more research on this since someone asked me to help them with this question, and the pandas source code has been revised somewhat since the accepted answer was written.

According to what I can tell from the source code:

Groupby returns the groups on a Grouper object (i.e. Grouper.groups), which are [“a specification for a groupby instruction”.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7757844f0bf6d42642008d18f372871158d4d788/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py#L111)

Ok, so what does that mean?

[“Groupers are ultimately index mappings.”](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7757844f0bf6d42642008d18f372871158d4d788/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py#L111)

I've always thought of this as meaning that groupby is creating a new object. It's not a full copy of the original dataframe, because you're performing selections and aggregations. So it's more like a transformation in that sense.

If your definition of a view is like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm): "A view is nothing more than a SQL statement that is stored in the database with an associated name. A view is actually a composition of a table in the form of a predefined SQL query", then I'm wondering if what you're really asking is whether the groupby operation has to be re-applied each time you execute the same grouping on the same dataframe?

If that's what you're asking, I'd say the answer is no, it's not like a view, as long as you store the result of the grouping operation. The output object of a grouped dataframe or series is a (new) dataframe or series.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information on the exact type of object returned by groupby. I used the term "view" in the question not in the sense of SQL, but rather following the pandas/numpy terminology, for example when discussing the effect of slicing operations. See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: The test is by setting a value on the group by. Will it affect the original data? It seems not.

Answer (score 4):

I know the original question was about memory usage, but for people coming to this question looking for whether modifications to the group chunk affect the original dataframe, the [pandas groupby user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation:%7E:text=Group%20chunks%20should%20be%20treated%20as%20immutable%2C%20and%20changes%20to%20a%20group%20chunk%20may%20produce%20unexpected%20results.) says:

> Group chunks should be treated as immutable, and changes to a group chunk may produce unexpected results.