# Does pandas groupby pass by reference or value?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame **data** and I'd like to split it by a certain column, **col**, according to

```
def split_by_column(data, column):

    chunk_list = [(k,g) for k, g in data.groupby(column)]
    return dict(chunk_list)


collection = split_by_column(data, 'col')
```

This way I can easily access and apply functions to this collection later.

If I for instance have an object which has both **data** and **collection** as instance variables, do I have two separate copies of the data in the memory or does the dictionary contain references to the appropriate chucks in data?

Comment: Very good question. This partly addresses the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711823/does-groupby-in-pandas-create-a-copy-of-the-data-or-just-a-view?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b':[6,9,8,9]})
print('data initial:',data)
def split_by_column(data, column):
    chunk_list = [(k,g) for k, g in data.groupby(column)]
    return dict(chunk_list)
collection = split_by_column(data, 'b')
print('collection initial:',collection)
```

Output is:

```
data initial:    a  b
0  1  6
1  2  9
2  3  8
3  4  9
collection initial: {6:    a  b
0  1  6, 8:    a  b
2  3  8, 9:    a  b
1  2  9
3  4  9}
```

If I change data now by

```
data.at[3,'a']=5
```

and print data and collection again, the output is this:

```
data new:    a  b
0  1  6
1  2  9
2  3  8
3  5  9
collection new: {6:    a  b
0  1  6, 8:    a  b
2  3  8, 9:    a  b
1  2  9
3  4  9}
```

Since I am also just starting to explore pandas, I can not tell you, what the underlying mechanisms are, but since the value 5 is only appearing in the dataframe, but not in the dict, I conclude, that you have two different copies of your data.

I hope, this is helpful for you.
Best, lepakk

Comment: (pass by value)

Comment: Indeed, this example is passing by value, since I called the original dataframe, manipulated it locally in the function and then assigned it (outside of the split_by_column function) to a variable "collection". As I understand it, data is never changed globally, but inside the function, a completely new variable chunk_list is created and locally it's reading something from data, but never puts a pointer to it. I found this topic quite confusing sometimes, but I liked [this page](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) very helpful to understand, how python makes copies (or not).